# composite function

Tags: functions

A colony of rabbits in outback Australia was studied. The colony began with 10 rabbits (5 pairs). Each female produced an average of 7 offspring of which 3 were female. 50 days later the original 5 females, plus the new female rabbits mated and again produced an average of 7 offspring of which 3 were female. This pattern of breeding continued. (a) Find a suitable model to represent the population of the rabbits after a given number of days and (b) if 50 days is counted as 1 breeding cycle, how many breeding cycles will it take for the population to reach 5000 rabbits?
[image]
Answer:

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $c_n$ is the number of couples after $n$ breeding cycles, you get $c_{n+1}=c_n+3c_n$, because every couple generates three females and each female will form a couple. So $c_{n+1}=4c_n$ and finding $c_n$ is easy, taking into account that $c_0=5$.
Let then $t_n$ be the total number of rabbits after $n$ breeding cycles. Every couple generates 7 rabbits, so that: $t_{n+1}=t_n+7c_n$, starting with $t_0=10$. This recursion is slightly more difficult to solve, but if you write down some of the summands composing each $t_n$ you should clearly see the pattern.